# References requested on departments with recitation sessions

Tags: soft-question, education

What physics departments offer recitation sessions for their physics courses on the undergraduate level?

If there is a site which has such info it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to search through every university's Course Catalog to see if such an option exists. Given that there's over 2500 colleges and universities in America alone, it'd be quite the undertaking for any person or group to compile such information. Especially since it's not really a useful fact.

Comment: Why the minus lower vote! My nephew is getting into college soon and he wants to major in physics. He wants to consider only departments that offer recitations for their courses. He tried looking for such info on the internet but he could not find anything.

Comment: A better way may be to narrow down a list of schools based on other criteria (cost, location, etc), then search that short list for recitation sections.